# Selling stuff...

Tags: untagged

Say you were thinking about building little noise modules to sell for a couple bucks each.

Further, say that you don't yet have a website and though you do in time intend to, at the moment you don't really have the knowhow/time to set up a site with it's own shopping basket.

Where would you host them?
Is there a BandCamp/Soundcloud for software?

EDIT:

I just found a wordpress plugin called Dippsy - http://dippsy.cz.cc/?page_id=57. Looks like just the ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use ebay.

However, it's pretty easy to buy a webdomain and server space, set up a wordpress site from a template and incorporate a paypal account into a website to sell your stuff.

Oh, and as far as I know there isn't an "App Store" specifically for what you're inquiring about.

Comment: I was under the impression that setting up retailer accounts was expensive and troublesome. Good to find out otherwise. 

Comment: Retailer accounts on ebay, or through paypal?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you could make Etsy work for it.

Answer (score 1):

Goodsie.com might suit your needs.

Comment: Snazzy! I likey. 